# What happened to Joseph after Jesus was 12?

Tags: gospels

It seems the last time we read about Joseph in the Gospels was after their visit to the Jerusalem temple when Jesus was 12.

From the time Jesus started his signs and wonders at the marriage in Cana, it appears Joseph was never mentioned again. And from that time forward the Bible evidently became silent about Joseph. So, what happened to Joseph after Jesus was 12?

Note:
I am just wondering! If he was dead, then, why was the Bible silent over a mention of this?

Answer (score 4):

This question may not really concern a matter of hermeneutics over a particular scripture, but there is an indication that Joseph had died before Jesus was crucified.  Before He breathed His last, Yeshua (Jesus) looked at Mary, and said,

> *"26 When Jesus therefore saw his mother, and the disciple standing by, whom he loved, he saith unto his mother, Woman, behold thy son!*
>
> *27 Then saith he to the disciple, Behold thy mother! And from that hour that disciple took her unto his own home."*  (John 19:26-27, KJV)

He gave John the responsibility of taking care of Mary, which would not have been necessary had Joseph still been living.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that between the time Jesus was 12 untile his death at 33yrs and 6 months his step father Joseph died as he tole John to take care of his mother just before he died:-

John 19:26
"26 So when Jesus saw his mother and the disciple whom he loved (John) standing nearby, he said to his mother: “Woman, see! Your son!” 27 Next he said to the disciple: “See! Your mother!” And from that hour on, the disciple took her into his own home.

If his father had been alive or his step brothers or step sisters had become beleives him he would not have done the above!

ethos